# MacOSX install MP4Box with brew fail

Tags: homebrew

When try below command to install MP4Box on MacOSX, It failed as below:

```
MP4Box$ brew install --fresh mp4box
==> Downloading https://downloads.sourceforge.net/gpac/gpac-0.5.0.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/gpac-0.5.0.tar.gz
==> Patching
patching file modules/ffmpeg_in/ffmpeg_decode.c
patching file modules/ffmpeg_in/ffmpeg_demux.c
patching file modules/ffmpeg_in/ffmpeg_in.h
==> ./configure --disable-wx --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gpac/0.5.0 --mandir=/usr/local/Cellar/gpac/0.5.0/share/man --ext
==> make
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [gm_ffmpeg_in.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [plugs] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

READ THIS: http://git.io/brew-troubleshooting

These open issues may also help:
gpac 0.5.0 doesn't build against ffmpeg 2.4.1 (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/32978)
```

Anything wrong with me?

Comment: That [issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/32978) on the last line looks related. I think you're going to have better luck [with Homebrew's support](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Troubleshooting.md#troubleshooting) that StackOverflow.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following script in Gist:
https://gist.github.com/orcaman/369e8da048b5d7345f5a

It works for me.

```
curl -#LO http://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsrc.v8c.tar.gz
curl -#LO http://download.sourceforge.net/libpng/libpng-1.6.8.tar.gz
curl -#LO http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/faac/faad2-src/faad2-2.7/faad2-2.7.tar.gz
curl -#LO ftp://ftp.mars.org/pub/mpeg/libmad-0.15.1b.tar.gz
curl -#LO http://liba52.sourceforge.net/files/a52dec-0.7.4.tar.gz
curl -#LO https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-2.0.3.tar.gz
svn export --non-interactive --trust-server-cert https://gpac.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/gpac/trunk/gpac

for file in `ls *.tar.*`; do
    tar -xzf $file
    rm $file
done

cd jpeg-*/
./configure && make -j 4 && sudo make install; cd ..

cd libpng-*/
./configure && make -j 4 && sudo make install; cd ..

cd faad2-*/
./configure --without-xmms --without-drm --without-mpeg4ip && make && sudo make install; cd ..

cd libmad-*/
sed -i -e 's/-march=i486//g' configure.ac
./configure && make -j 4 && sudo make install; cd ..

cd a52dec-*/
./configure --enable-shared && make -j 4 && sudo make install; cd ..

cd SDL2-*/
./configure --without-x && make -j 4 && sudo make install; cd ..

cd gpac/
./configure && make lib && make apps && sudo make install lib && sudo make install
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.